# How do i manually add a legend to a ggplot and geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting 2 sets of data on the same plot using ggplot. I have specified the colour for each data set, but there is no legend that comes out when the dot plot is generated.

What can i do to manually add a legend?

```
# Create an index to hold values of m from 1 to 100
m_index <- (1:100)

data_frame_50 <- data(prob_max_abs_cor_50)
data_frame_20 <- data.frame(prob_max_abs_cor_20)



library(ggplot2)
plot1 <- ggplot(data_frame_50, mapping = aes(x = m_index, 
               y = prob_max_abs_cor_50),
               colour = 'red')  + 
    geom_point() + 
         ggplot(data_frame_20, mapping = aes(x = m_index,
               y = prob_max_abs_cor_20),
               colour = 'blue') + 
    geom_point() 


plot1 + labs(x = " Values of m  ", 
             y = " Maximum Absolute Correlation ",
             title = "Dot plot of probability")
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can simplify the question - providing only the data which feeds into your plot(s), and the ggplot code? You're more likely to get a good response if you limit the preamble to the immediate context of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest neatening your `ggplot` code a little. This is equivalent to your posted code;

```
ggplot() +
   geom_point(data = data_frame_50, aes(x = m_index, y = prob_max_abs_cor_50,
     colour = 'red')) +
   geom_point(data = data_frame_20, aes(x = m_index, y = prob_max_abs_cor_20,
     colour = 'blue')) +
   labs(x = " Values of m  ", y = " Maximum Absolute Correlation ",
     title = "Dot plot of probability")
```

You won't get a legend here, because you are plotting different datasets with only one category in each. You need to have a single dataset with a column grouping your data (i.e. `20` or `50`). So using some example data, this is the equivalent of what you are plotting and ggplot won't provide a legend;

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width), colour = 'red') +
  geom_point(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length), colour = 'blue')
```

If you want to colour by category, include a `colour` argument inside the `aes` call;

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width, 
     colour = factor(Species)))
```

Have a look at the `iris` dataset to get a sense of how you need to shape your data. It's hard to give precise advice, because you haven't provided an idea of what your data look like, but something like this might work;

```
df.20 <- data.frame("m" = 1:100, "Group" = 20, "Numbers" = prob_max_abs_cor_20)
df.50 <- data.frame("m" = 1:100, "Group" = 50, "Numbers" = prob_max_abs_cor_50)
df.All <- rbind(df.20, df.50)
```

Comment: I ran the first chunk of the code and a colour legend came out. How am i able to change the title of the legend and the labelling of the red and blue dots respectively?

Comment: There are lots of questions related to these on stackoverflow. Or try an internet search for "ggplot change legend title". The website Cookbook for R is a good resource; http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/ If you absolutely can't find what you are looking for, I would suggest posting another question.

Comment: rbind does not work for me, so does list, numeric etc

Comment: Well it will depend on your data structure. Those were suggestions for how to go about creating a dataframe, but you need to provide some example data for people to help you. I would suggest posting a new question outlining your data problems as they are separate to the issue of ggplot legends.